# Замена фрагмента с табом из фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть NavigationView с пунктами из фрагментов, один из фрагментов содержит ViewPager и TabLayout с тремя фрагментами. При выборе другого пункта меню заменяется текущий фрагмент, а фрагменты в табе остаются висеть активными. Поэтому при возвращении к этому фрагменту фрагменты пустые висят. Что мне может помочь в данной ситуации?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int LAYOUT =R.layout.main_layout;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppDefault);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(LAYOUT);
    initNavigationView();
    initToolbar();
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.view_navigation_open,R.string.view_navigation_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MainFragment(),"TAG")
                .commit();
    }
}

private void initNavigationView() {
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.draw);
    NavigationView view = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.actionWhereEat:
                    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,mainFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
                case R.id.actionMyOrders:
                    BasketFragment basketFragment = new BasketFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,basketFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;
                case R.id.actionPromotions:
                    break;
                case R.id.actionPersonalRoom:
                    break;
            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
private void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
}}
```

**MainFragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPager pager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_fragment,container,false);
    initTabs(mainFragment);
    return mainFragment;
}

private void initTabs(View v) {
    pager = (ViewPager)v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabsActionAdapter adapter = new TabsActionAdapter(v.getContext(), getFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
}}
```

**TabActionAdapter**

```
public class TabsActionAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Map<Integer, AbstractFragment> tabs;
private Context context;

public TabsActionAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    initTabsMaps(context);
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabs.get(position).getTitle();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return tabs.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabs.size();
}

private void initTabsMaps(Context context) {
    tabs = new HashMap<>();
    tabs.put(0, MapFragment.getInstance(context));
    tabs.put(1, MenuFragment.getInstance(context));
    tabs.put(2, PaymentFragment.getInstance(context));
}}
```

Comment: Вложенные фрагменты = проблемы. Перенеделайте этот фрагмент с фрагментами в активити.

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет!

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.